# How to prevent duplicates when using date field?

Tags: custom-field

I have a very simple custom object with just two custom fields, a dropdown `yes/no` and a `date`. This custom object serves as a related list for `account` and should get multiple entries with the combination of date and yes/no.

But how to prevent duplicates. I only want one entry per date. For other custom fields, I could set `Do not allow duplicate values`, but for `date` fields, this option is not available.

Are there any easy workarounds, not forcing me to code triggers?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with an invisible text field that gets updated with data when entering a new combination, following [this advice](http://www.forcetree.com/2010/07/unique-field-combination-in-salesforce.html). It failed however, as I cannot update a text field (which prevents duplicates) with a date entry. Is there any way to convert date to text?

Comment: Can you not use TEXT( your_date_field__c ) ?

Comment: I am working on a solution with VLOOKUP, almost done. BTW do you mind your Name field value being hijacked with a the date value? What is your Name field currently Text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a hidden text field and mark it as unique when you're creating the field.

Create a workflow to copy the Text of your date field concatenated with the AccountId (and maybe yes/no) to this new field. Set the workflow to fire every time the record is created or edited and if your date field is not null / changes.

I have a feeling Text (DateField) works

```
AccountId + TEXT(DateField__c)
```

but failing that you can construct a string using

```
 AccountId + TEXT(Year(DateField__c)) + TEXT(MONTH(DateField__c)) + TEXT(DAY(DateField__c))
```

What this mechanism does is it causes an error to surface when the workflow attempts to insert the same date string in the hidden field which is unique.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's the combination of Account and CreatedDate that should be considered unique I'd do this:

- Create a new Text field, *Dupe Checker*
- Set the *Unique* flag on the field
- Create a new workflow rule with the following simple condition: `TRUE`
- Add a new workflow field update to the workflow, setting the Dupe Checker field to something like `Account__c & YEAR(Date_Field__c) & MONTH(Date_Field__c) & DAY(Date_Field__c)`

The syntax is untested, but the theory should hold.

Comment: ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Account__c) || ISCHANGED(Date_field__c) ;) Besides it seems it's not for NOW() but for some "Date_Field__c"

Comment: @eyescream, good catch. I assumed it would be the date the record was created, but after re-reading the post it's obvious you're correct. I've updated my answer to include this.